# PDF form is missing information entered on a Windows PC

Tags: macos, windows, pdf, preview

I have a 3rd party form which has a lot of fields to be filled in. I started entering the information on a Windows PC and saved it to Dropbox. When I open the form in Apple Preview on my OS X Yosemite machine the fields that I filed in are all blank! If I open it in Adobe Reader instead the information is present but when I save the file and open it in Windows again all of the previously saved information from my initial Windows session has gone. Please tell me how I can stop this happening as I use these forms on a regular basis and I need to edit them in Windows 7 and Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Which versions of PDF viewers are you using? Also, NEVER, EVER do something with forms using Preview.app. Preview.app is too dumb to deal with smart forms, and when saving, it reliably messes up the PDF that it is no longer usable.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe recommends:

> Mac users: don't use Preview
>
> For Macintosh system users: DO NOT use the Preview program to fill in
>   the PDF form. Adobe Reader is the only program that will allow you to
>   work with the form properly, and allow us to read the results once
>   back on a Windows machine.

The fillable PDF forms are created with Adobe app. If opened with Preview it will completely mess-up that capability, so newer open it with Preview. Happy filling.